# Ошибка при совместном подключении модулей asyncio и aioredis

Tags: python, python-3.x, redis

Нет возможности запустить скрипт из - за использования `class TimeoutError`. Как в следующем коде оставить возможность подключения обоих модулей и избавиться от ошибки?

```
import asyncio
import aioredis

async def main():
    redis = await aioredis.create_redis_pool(('localhost', 6379))
    await redis.set('mykey', 'Hello world')
    value = await redis.get('mykey')
    print(value)


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Код ошибки:

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/goinfre/werewolf/Documents/gitlab/Python_Bootcamp._Day_08-1/src/main.py", line 5, in <module>
    import aioredis
  File "/opt/goinfre/werewolf/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aioredis/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from aioredis.client import Redis, StrictRedis
  File "/opt/goinfre/werewolf/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aioredis/client.py", line 32, in <module>
    from aioredis.connection import (
  File "/opt/goinfre/werewolf/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aioredis/connection.py", line 33, in <module>
    from .exceptions import (
  File "/opt/goinfre/werewolf/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aioredis/exceptions.py", line 14, in <module>
    class TimeoutError(asyncio.TimeoutError, builtins.TimeoutError, RedisError):
TypeError: duplicate base class TimeoutError
```

Comment: Зачем вам еще один класс TimeoutError? Просто импортируйте TimeoutError из aioredis.exceptions.

Comment: @insolor.      Мне он вобще не нужен так - то

Comment: Тогда уберите этот класс из своего кода, в чем проблема?

Comment: @insolor.      проблема лишь в том что запуск скрипта при 2 лишь include вызывает ошибку без всего остального

Comment: Т.е. когда просто добавляете импорты, возникает эта ошибка при запуске? Оставьте в вопросе только тот код, который демонстрирует проблему (если уже на импортах вылетает, то только их и оставьте)

Comment: Тут посмотрите: https://github.com/aio-libs/aioredis-py/issues/1409  А нет возможности более старый питон использовать? В 3.11 много чего пока не работает.

Comment: @CrazyElf, aioredis вообще заархивирован, рекомендуют использовать пакет redis, см. ответ. Я предполагаю, что redis/redis-py уже обновлен под Python 3.11

Comment: @CrazyElf, по крайней мере CI на Python 3.11 запускают: https://github.com/redis/redis-py/actions/runs/4538296636, так что предполагаю, что уже обновились

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ошибка `TypeError: duplicate base class TimeoutError` на строке `class TimeoutError(asyncio.TimeoutError, builtins.TimeoutError, RedisError):` возникает из-за того, что в Python 3.11 имя `asyncio.TimeoutError` сделано псевдонимом `builtins.TimeoutError`, см. [документацию](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-exceptions.html?highlight=timeouterror#asyncio.TimeoutError):

> *exception* asyncio.**TimeoutError**[¶](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-exceptions.html?highlight=timeouterror#asyncio.TimeoutError)
>
> A deprecated alias of
> [`TimeoutError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#TimeoutError),
> raised when the operation has exceeded the given deadline.
>
> *Changed in version 3.11:* This class was made an alias of [`TimeoutError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#TimeoutError).

Получается, что фактически один и тот же класс указан базовым классом два раза.

Решение - или откатиться на Python 3.10, или использовать пакет `redis` вместо `aioredis`, см. README репозитория [aio-libs/aioredis-py](https://github.com/aio-libs/aioredis-py):

> Aioredis is now in redis-py 4.2.0rc1+
>
> To install, just do `pip install redis>=4.2.0rc1`. The code is almost
> the exact same. You will just need to import like so:
>
> `from redis import asyncio as aioredis`
>
> This way you don't have to change all your code, just the imports.

Сам репозиторий [aio-libs/aioredis-py](https://github.com/aio-libs/aioredis-py) сделан архивным, и видимо уже обновляться не будет. Дальнейшая разработка ведется в репозитории [redis/redis-py](https://github.com/redis/redis-py).